# Swift setting object's properties to nil

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, reference, pass-by-reference

I am new to Swift and I'm facing a problem.

My problem is quite simple:

I have a simple class with some object in it (declared in their own file) :

```
class Outcome : NSObject {
   var foo : SomeClass? 
   var doo : OtherClass?
   var roo: AnotherClass?

}
```

What I want to do is when an object of the class is set, set all the other object to nil, so I used the `didSet` feature and add a `resetData` method that is supposed to set all the object to `nil`, except the one I just set.

The class looks like this :

```
    class Outcome : NSObject {
       var foo : SomeClass? {
    didSet { self.resetData(exeption: foo!) }
       var doo : OtherClass? {
           didSet { self.resetData(exeption: doo!) }
      }
       var roo: AnotherClass? {
            didSet { self.resetData(exeption: roo!) }
       }

    func resetData (exeption: AnyObject) {

    var allObjects = NSArray(array: [self.foo ?? NSNull(), self.doo ?? NSNull(), self.roo ?? NSNull()])

    for var anObject in (allObjects as NSArray as! [NSObject?]) {
        if exeption.isEqual(anObject) == false  {
            anObject = nil 
        }
    }
   }    
 }
```

The idea of the resetData method is to set all the objects to `nil` except the exception (which is the object I just set in my view controller)

The code is working and the instruction `anObject = nil` is executed, but the problem is that when I set a set a beakpoint I can clearly see that the object is not `nil`, so this does not do what I want.

I think it is a question of reference, I do not really get it, is it possible to set an object to `ni`l ? Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: `anObject = nil` modifies the loop variable only, not the class property.

Comment: Your loop simply sets the local variable `anObject` to nil. It doesn't set the relevant property to `nil`. There is no trivial way to do what you want with a single function.  You will need to explicitly set all of the other properties to `nil` in each `didSet` (i.e. `self.doo = nil`), but this seems like an unusual thing to do and there may be some better way to achieve what you are really after

Comment: Why don't you use an `enum` (with associated values)  instead if the values are mutually exclusive?

Comment: Thank you Martin, but i do not get it, goal is to loop to all the other objects (because there are much more than 3), you think i could do this with enum ?

Comment: If you want only one property to have a value at a time, then yes, you could use an enumeration with each case having the appropriate associated value type for any number of possible values

Comment: Thank you, Paul, i do not get it right now, will try to look something.

Comment: Paul, may be can point me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your loop does not modify the class
properties at all, only the `anObject` loop variable.

If the intention is to define a type which holds *either* an instance
of `SomeClass` *or* an instance of `OtherClass` *or* an instance
of `AnotherClass` then an `enum` would be a better choice:

```
enum Outcome {
    case foo(SomeClass)
    case doo(OtherClass)
    case roo(AnotherClass)
}
```

Usage example:

```
var outCome = Outcome.foo(SomeClass())
print(outCome) // foo(<SomeClass: 0x1009000b0>)
// ...

outCome = .doo(OtherClass())
print(outCome) // doo(<OtherClass: 0x100d00540>)
```

Comment: No this is not want i want to do, i want some to be nil when i set outcome. That is why i used a loop. In what u do, Outcome.some still has a value.
But thank you.

Comment: @F.Fondacci: No, it doesn't. The second assignment replaces the first.